# Python Implemenatation of SPSS's Two-Step Clustering

Tags: python, clustering, spss, hierarchical-clustering

I want to perform a clustering on data with ~40 binary features. I was recommended the two-step approach by [Chiu et al.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/502512.502549?casa_token=OyIxEk43ypwAAAAA:HfcJyCDfCeRf5xIytdz9pKWZMcYWAXFcVy0pzhQkNA0r_uF-ctCCWJ5pXY5hdMOJHXi8PRZiEdpD). They basically use a BIRCH variant to determine pre-clusters and then perform agglomorative clustering on these. However, I cannot find an implementation of this two-step approach and generally struggle to find resources about this approach via Google. All sources that I saw used SPSS, which has an [implementation of this approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstats.stackexchange.com%2fquestions%2f567024%2fpython-implemenatation-of-two-step-clustering).

### Questions

- Is there a Python implementation of the algorithm by Chiu et al.? If not, how to reproduce it using Scipy, Scikit Learn, etc.?
- Bonus: In the context of the pre-clustering, what does "First, the entire data were scanned and pre-clusters were formed, based on a sequential clustering approach using log-likelihood distance measure as the similarity criterion" mean?